# Determining Thousandths in a number

Tags: python, rounding

If an aircraft is flying VFR in the US, if the heading is east, the altitude must be an odd thousand plus 500 feet (1500, 3500, 5500, etc). If flying west, the altitude must be an even thousand plus 500 feet (2500, 4500, 6500, etc). If I input a given altitude, but it is the wrong (odd or even) for the heading, how do I get Python to correct it next higher odd or even thousandths (1500 becomes 2500, 6500 becomes 7500, etc)? We never round down for altitudes. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Right now it's just a single line using the if altitude %2  = 0 statement, to find out if the number is even, but that uses the rightmost digit to determine odd or even.

Comment: I see, so you want to determine whether the left most digit is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide your altitude by 1000.0 and cast to an int which would drop the decimal:

`if int(altitude/1000.0) % 2 == 0`

Then you can do whatever you want with that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [math.ceil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) to do this:

```
>>> import math
>>> def next_alt(alt):
...    return (math.ceil(alt/1000)+1)*1000+500
... 
>>> next_alt(2500)
3500.0
>>> next_alt(3500)
4500.0
```

Which could then be used in a function this way:

```
def set_alt(heading, alt):
    if 0<=heading<=179:       # odd + 500
        return alt if alt / 1000 % 2 else (math.ceil(alt/1000)+1)*1000+500
    else:
        return alt if not alt / 1000 % 2 else (math.ceil(alt/1000)+1)*1000+500
```

(If Python 3, you need `//` instead of `/`)

```
>>> set_alt(290, 3500)
4500
>>> set_alt(90, 3500)
3500
```